# 96 KHz EQ Plugin

Tags: 96k, eq, hum, removal

I'm mastering some 96KHz material that has a nasty hum running around 32KHz, which mostly I can only hear when playing back at half speed or scrubbing. As a last step of the mastering process, I'm doing some light denoising using Izotope RX2. If I tweak the envelope for RX's Denoiser, I can pull down the offending frequency a bit, but I'd prefer to notch it out with a sharp EQ.

The problem I'm running into is that my plugins only allow a maximum frequency setting of around 21 KHz. Does anyone have any suggestions for an EQ that can pull down frequencies above the human hearing spectrum or a workaround?

This obviously isn't a major problem, but now that I've realized the limitation, I'm curious if there's an easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in ProTools you could import the audio into a 48k session without sample rate conversion, so its playing at half speed, then notch the whine out, and process/print it & then export it at 48kHz... Then reset/hack the sample rate back to 96kHz

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because most equalizers are meant for audio that's in the human hearing range! I bet it's just left out of the implementations, because it would be an useless feature for most users.

iZotope RX 2's spectral view for example does adjust to the sample rate of the source, IIRC. But that's a different type of tool in a sense, made for audio restoration.

Comment: A very valid point. My primary reason for wanting for an EQ that can handle the higher frequency range at this moment is simply that when I'm scrubbing at lower-than-real-time speeds to track down and isolate clicks and pops, the offending hum comes into the audible spectrum and unfortunately has a high amplitude, making it quite annoying.

Obviously not a dealbreaker in any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a recording I made some months ago, where an harmonic hum were present over 20KHz, with at least 3 harmonics. I used Hum Removal on RX2 to successfully get rid of them.

Answer (score 0):

http://hofa-plugins.de/pages/start_en/hofa-iq-eq_en.php